# A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_local_notifications'. > No signature of method

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKufw.png)A problem occurred evaluating project ':flutter_local_notifications'.

> No signature of method: build_3pmp7jstj0pow6f927vbzyvxq.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_3pmp7jstj0pow6f927vbzyvxq$_run_closure2) values: [build_3pmp7jstj0pow6f927vbzyvxq$_run_closure2@51769b21]

Answer (score 1):

I was getting about the same error on my flutter project

> problem occurred evaluating project ':package_info_plus'.
> No signature of method: build_3eu717v9rh6kgexbrrk7kr5bl.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_3eu717v9rh6kgexbrrk7kr5bl$_run_closure2) values: [build_3eu717v9rh6kgexbrrk7kr5bl$_run_closure2@73bdd7aa]

I accidentally solved this problem by committing `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `build.gradle` files the following changes

1. gradle-wrapper.properties:
   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip`
   to
   `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip`
2. build.gradle:

   `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.1'`

link: [click](https://youtu.be/GrmVWl4YtG8)